# Ionic 2 datetime displaying wrong year

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have a problem with display format in ion-datetime. I don't know why ionic 2 cut last 2 characters of year.

I have code:

```
   <ion-datetime displayFormat="MMM DD, YYYY" [(ngModel)]="form.dateOfBirth" name="dateOfBirth"></ion-datetime>
```

And result is:
[image]

It is a problem with column width. How can I override this size?

Answer (score 0):

```
.picker-col{
//here write your custom style to increase width
min-width:64px
}
```

Comment: when I mannualy edited this value in firebug, then it works, but when I put it in scss file, then this value is not overrided.

Answer (score 0):

For ionic 2
I figured out the solution by adding following to variables.scss for both ios and android

```
$picker-md-column-padding: 0 0px !default;
$picker-ios-column-padding: 0 0px !default;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
 You can try this code it's works for me hope it will help you.
```

date.html

```
 <ion-list>
        <ion-item >
            <ion-label class="capitalize">Date</ion-label>
            <ion-datetime  displayFormat="MMM DD YYYY"[(ngModel)]="dateData" (ionChange)="dateChanged()"></ion-datetime>
        </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
```

showDate.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
    selector: 'date',
    templateUrl: 'date.html'
})
export class Date {
        dateData: string;
    constructor() { }
    dateChanged() {
        console.log(this.dateData)
}
}
```

Comment: It's problem with width of this columns